# Get CL_INVALID_COMMAND_QUEUE when do clFinish(queue) in OpenCL

Tags: c++, opencl, nvidia

Windows 10

C++ 17

mingw64 g++ compiler

NVIDIA 1080 with official drivers

I'm writing test code under OpenCL. The kernel is executed (debugged this), but I'm not sure that every work item is executed. The queue gives error CL_INVALID_COMMAND_QUEUE when trying to apply clFinish(queue).

If I make every kernel do output to the console, it outputs only few thousands lines (must be above one million). Maybe it's because clFinish(queue) from host interrupts execution. After that another call to the kernel does not start execution.

The clEnqueueNDRangeKernel itself does not produce errors the first time or later, the clCreateCommandQueue (when creating a queue) doesn't as well.

Code before invoking kernel:

```
cl_command_queue queue = clCreateCommandQueue(context, device, 0, NULL);
if (sizeUpdate) {
   sizeUpdate = false;
   taskWidth = align(WxSize, 128);                //align funtion Ffinds the smallest number divisible by 128, that is local group size in X dimension
   bufferWidth = taskWidth * 4;                   //because four uint8 per pixel
   PIXELS = new uint8_t [WySize * bufferWidth];   //array for final output
   buffer = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY, bufferWidth * sizeof(uint8_t) * WySize, NULL, NULL);
}
invoke_kernel(kernel, queue, buffer, PIXELS, taskWidth, WySize, bufferWidth);
```

Invoke kernel function:

```
void invoke_kernel(cl_kernel kernel, cl_command_queue queue, cl_mem buffer, uint8_t* PIXELS, int taskWidth, int WySize, int bufferWidth) {
    clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), &buffer);
    clSetKernelArg(kernel, 1, sizeof(int), &bufferWidth);
    //clSetKernelArg(kernel, arg_index, arg_size, arg_value);
    const size_t local_size[2] = {128, 1};
    const size_t global_size[2] = {taskWidth, WySize};
    clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue, kernel, 2, NULL, global_size, local_size, 0, NULL, NULL);
    int error = clFinish(queue);
    clEnqueueReadBuffer(queue, buffer, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(uint8_t) * bufferWidth * WySize, PIXELS, 0, NULL, NULL);
    std::cout << error << "\n"; Sleep(5000);
}
```

Kernel itself:

```
__kernel void main_kernel(__global uint8* buffer, int buffer_width) {
    int delta = get_global_id(0) * 4 + get_global_id(1) * buffer_width;
    buffer[delta] = 127;
    buffer[delta+1] = 127;
    buffer[delta+2] = 127;
    buffer[delta+3] = 127;
}
```

I made sure the variables values were correct. I tried to remove clFinish, but got error -5 in clEnqueueReadBuffer, i.e. CL_OUT_OF_RESOURCES (however, it appears in any case).

Comment: I tried to comment all kernel and there is no problem with queue

Comment: Debugging OpenCL programs can be difficult. I've found it to be well worth investing the time in checking the response codes of every API call. Sometimes they are the function value, and other times you have to get it by passing an argument by reference. You should probably start by finding the first occurrence of a call that is not CL_SUCCESS.

Comment: clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), &buffer); looks suspicious. It's a while since I've done any of this but I don't think you've allocated your buffer correctly. You either need to allocate it from the host as normal, preferably with 4k alignment, or get the API to allocate it for you with the CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR flag. See https://registry.khronos.org/OpenCL/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clCreateBuffer.html

Comment: I fixed this. Somehow cl_uint8 is 32, but uint8_t is 8 bits. I used char type and it works!